# Why doesn't this jQuery add an image to my div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the [add function](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add an HTML fragment to a div but I can't get it to work.  My code:

```
$('#curveContainer').add('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Blue-dot-5px.png" alt="test" />');
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/7a86g/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), not `add()`.

From the `add()` documentation...

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

`append()` will add the new content to the DOM

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/7a86g/5/

You can also use `html()` to completely replace the contents of the matched element.